# Could not load file or assembly 'PROJECT NAME, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have WPF application,it is based on Awesomium.NET browser example, suddenly it shows errors like:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Project Name, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And:

> The resource "XXXX" could not be resolved.

I'am sure that it worked before, I have no change, try to restart , rebuild, clean, start VS community as Administrator, nothing work for me.
If I run the application I get this Exception:

> Additional information: Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.

Comment: Have to tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3748034/2819451) to mention the RD as Pack URI.  Also, try to run the solution with different platform (x86/x64).

Comment: Is the project present in solution or locally?

Comment: @Gopichandar all my resouces are Pack URI, and I tried to change the platform, but not work

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh it is in solution with other projects

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBa Try to close the VS and kill the vshost setup on TaskManager and then open it again.  May be silly and but it worked for me sometimes.