# How can i get my usercontrol to use the styles in a resource dictionary held in a seperate class library?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class Library called 'Style' which has a xaml file called 'Controls.xaml' inside it. Controls.xaml looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Style x:Key="DriveImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DriveLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri Light" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I then referenced 'Styles' in my main project and in the user control where i want to use it i added it to the Resources section:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles;component/Controls.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

No errors show. However when i run the application i get the error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line number '13' and line position '18'.
```

with the inner exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Styles, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Styles, Culture=neutral"}
```

Could anyone please help me out here, I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow Ok figured it out... It was really quite simple but i can be blinded to the simple solutions some times...

Basically i needed to add a reference to 'Styles' in the actual main application too. Silly i didn't think of this.

Here is a link to the thread that helped me:

[WPF UserControl cannot find XAML resource in referencing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747972/wpf-usercontrol-cannot-find-xaml-resource-in-referencing-project)